# Como criar expressão que retorne 1,12,123,1234 em Python

Tags: python

Estou a aprender o básico de `python` e deparei-me com um exercício onde tenho de construir a seguinte sequência:

```
1   
12  
123  
1234  
12345  
123456  
1234567  
12345678  
123456789
```

Penso que seja algo muito simples de se fazer até, mas alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código é bem simples:

```
st = ''
for i in range(1, 10):
    st += str(i)
    print st
```

Teste online: [link](http://goo.gl/sWDDYH).

Comment: Acredito que você não deveria dar a resposta para o OP e sim incentivá-lo a pensar como resolver.

Comment: Olá! Isso acabou por resolver. Eu estava tentando criar isso usando a função while e não estava a conseguir chegar aos valores. Afinal o truque estava em fazer através de string e não em numérico. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja generalizar esta questão ao ponto de poder `especificar` o número de linhas deste triângulo, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Capturando e tratando a quantidade de linhas:
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite o número de linhas do triângulo: '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[39m')
            n = int(input('Digite o número de linhas do triângulo: '))
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[39m')

print(f'\033[32mO triângulo criado com colunas iguais é: ')
# Controla o número de linhas
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    # Controla a organização e inserção dos elementos na linha.
    for i in range(1, c + 1):
        print(i, end='')
        print('  ' if i < 10 else '  ', end='')
    print()
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/rwlgcjri-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que neste algoritmo você pode `especificar` a quantidade de linhas que serão exibidas.

Outra coisa, o `primeiro for` controla o número de linhas do triângulo. Já o `segundo for`, controla a inserção e organização dos elementos.

Observe também, que este algoritmo pode trabalhar com um número indefinido de linhas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um laço que tenho o valor mínimo e rode enquanto seja menor e/ou igual que o valor máximo e imprimir o valor antes do incremento.